# FifoDiskQueue: Connecting to previously created queue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have started using [FifoDiskQueue](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/queuelib) and it's great!
I just don't understand how to reconnect to a file queue that is already in disk. Here is an example:

```
>>> from queuelib import FifoDiskQueue
>>> queue = FifoDiskQueue("queue")
>>> queue.push('item')
>>> queue.info
{'tail': [0, 0, 0], 'head': [0, 1], 'chunksize': 100000, 'size': 1}
>>> queue = FifoDiskQueue("queue")
>>> queue.info
{'tail': [0, 0, 0], 'head': [0, 0], 'chunksize': 100000, 'size': 0}
```

When I try to reconnect to the pre-existing FifoDiskQueue with another reference, it thinks that the size of the queue is 0. Why? I can see the file on disk and it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
>>> queue.close()
```

before re-opening the queue. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: I think so, but what if my program exists before having the chance to do this? Suppose it crashes. What do I do on the next run?

Comment: Program crashes are usually bad thing and causing trouble. But ... you can  close the queue each time you are done with push()es to minimize the risk of loss of data (by the way: you comment didn't somehow show up in my comment alert area - that't the reason I am responding with delay.)
If my answer solved your issue please accept it as answer and if this comment is helpful either you can as a bonus upvote it)